# Speeding up a "Multiple Version Jump" Database Update

Tags: mysql, performance, setup-script

I'm working a project to bring up an old Magento EE system up to date with the  latest and greatest version of EE.  Running some tests locally on my development laptop (spinning disks), the Setup Resource Migration scripts took around 90 minutes to run.

On one hand I was surprised it was only 90 minutes, given the number of new indexes and foreign keys an upgrade adds. At the same time, I'm not wild about taking my client's side down for 90 minutes when we perform the actual upgrade. (or, alternately, dealing with keeping the old store up for those 90 minutes and reconciling and new orders, customers, or data that's added to the system)

Is there any known science for speeding up the setup resource script running?  (Skipping certain unneeded updates, temporary tweaks to my.cnf, etc.)

Comment: I am a fan of strongarming them into taking the site down in maintenance while performing upgrade. It's somewhat unreasonable that you can't find a 3 hour window with low sales volume. Of course, I like doing cool crap, so why not accept the challenge...

Comment: I'd support Phil on this - even Apple puts their store into maintenance mode regularly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** While I usually chastise link-only answers I do not have the personal experience in this area to provide real help. So I am making this answer CW.

---

The ECG team came up with a way of aggregating the db upgrade scripts to 'replay' the upgrade without stepping through all of the alter statements, etc.

https://github.com/magento-ecg/Magento-Upgrade-Replay

Unsurprisingly AOE (@fbrnc) have also done something similar and it seems these two projects may be somewhat related:

https://github.com/fbrnc/Magento-Upgrade-Replay